# Is there a way to insert vector<unsigned char> into postgresql table, with bytea attribute, with no UTF8 encoding error?

Tags: c++, postgresql, stringstream, libpqxx

I get `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe0 0x20 0x63` when i try to execute sql statement (insert into) of a std::vector into a bytea.

I'm using `c++ (11), and pqxx postgresql client, and posgresql 9.6` . I need to write into db a byte stream (vector).

Very often my code works well, but now i faced with the following error:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe0 0x20 0x63

From  pgAdmin4 i get:

> show client_encoding;  -> unicode

From c++, i fill this vector from std::stringstream using the following code:

```
//mOutputStream is std::stringstream correctly filled
mOutputStream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
int sizeOS = mOutputStream.tellg();
mOutputStream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
mOutputStream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

std::streampos vecSize;
mOutputStream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
vecSize = mOutputStream.tellg();
mOutputStream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

//std::vector<unsigned char>& arrayChar
arrayChar.reserve(vecSize);

arrayChar.insert(arrayChar.begin(),                  

std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(mOutputStream),
std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>());
```

Then, using pqxx library, i create a sql statement:

```
sql = "Insert into public.\"MyFile\" (id,rawdata) values ($1,$2);";
/* Create a transactional object. */
pqxx::work W(C);
C.prepare("InsertRaw", sql);
...
void * bin_data = static_cast<void*>(arrayChar.data());  
size_t bin_size = arrayChar.size(); // ...and the size of the binary data

pqxx::binarystring blob(bin_data, bin_size);
//at this line i get the error of UTF8 encoding
pqxx::result r = W.prepared("InsertRaw")(idFile.c_str())(blob).exec();

W.commit();
C.disconnect();
```

This is the error i get:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe0 0x20 0x63

Answer (score 0):

`pqxx::binarystring` is for bytea data you're reading from the server.

For submitting binary data, the [doc](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/a00843.html) says:

> To convert the other way, i.e. from a raw series of bytes to a string
>   suitable for inclusion as bytea values in your SQL, use the
>   transaction's esc_raw() functions.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your suggestion. I tried with esc_raw function, but i get the same error. I'm wondering if issue should be solved from c++ side or postgresql side (i.e. assign to rawColumn in my table a specific encoding or changing rawColumn type from bytea to string, keeping in mind that data should be very huge ... sometimes 1 GB). Kind regards